# How to check which topic is changed after one action?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I click one button and want to know which topic is changed because of this action, what can I do to find the changing topic(s)?

For example, I run

```
  roslaunch sia10d_mesh_arm_navigation planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_sia10d_mesh.launch
```

I run rostopic list to get

```
 /clock 
 /goal 
 /ik_solution_display 
 /initialpose 
 /joint_states 
 /ompl_planning/sync_planning_scene/cancel 
 /ompl_planning/sync_planning_scene/feedback 
 /ompl_planning/sync_planning_scene/goal 
 /ompl_planning/sync_planning_scene/result 
 /ompl_planning/sync_planning_scene/status 
 /planning_scene_markers 
 /planning_scene_markers_array 
 /planning_scene_validity_server/sync_planning_scene/cancel 
 /planning_scene_validity_server/sync_planning_scene/feedback 
 /planning_scene_validity_server/sync_planning_scene/goal 
 /planning_scene_validity_server/sync_planning_scene/result 
 /planning_scene_validity_server/sync_planning_scene/status 
 /planning_scene_visualizer_markers 
 /planning_scene_visualizer_markers_array 
 /planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_controls/feedback 
 /planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_controls/update 
 /planning_scene_warehouse_viewer_controls/update_full 
 /rosout 
 /rosout_agg 
 /sia10d_mesh_manipulator_kinematics/sync_planning_scene/cancel 
 /sia10d_mesh_manipulator_kinematics/sync_planning_scene/feedback 
 /sia10d_mesh_manipulator_kinematics/sync_planning_scene/goal 
 /sia10d_mesh_manipulator_kinematics/sync_planning_scene/result 
 /sia10d_mesh_manipulator_kinematics/sync_planning_scene/status 
 /tf 
 /trajectory_filter_server/sync_planning_scene/cancel 
 /trajectory_filter_server/sync_planning_scene/feedback 
 /trajectory_filter_server/sync_planning_scene/goal 
 /trajectory_filter_server/sync_planning_scene/result 
 /trajectory_filter_server/sync_planning_scene/status 
 /warehouse/arm_navigation/motion_plan_request/inserts 
 /warehouse/arm_navigation/outcome/inserts 
 /warehouse/arm_navigation/paused_state/inserts 
 /warehouse/arm_navigation/planning_scene/inserts 
 /warehouse/arm_navigation/trajectory/inserts
```

How to do that?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30755/how-to-check-which-topic-is-changed-after-one-action?/) by [yichu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2075/yichu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could look which nodes are being launched looking rxgraph before and after you run that command.
Once identified them you can look at which topic are publishing each one of them...

---

Originally posted by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) with karma: 195 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0